# How good are heat pump water heaters compared to propane or electric?

Tags: water-heater, heat-pump

I want to replace my 1996 Bradford White propane water heater with a heat pump water heater. Will it be saving costs for me? Located in NY.

Comment: we just spent 4 days w/o power and it was nice to still have hot water. might not be your main criterion, but is something to consider.

Comment: https://youtu.be/omivdhxdGv0?t=277   @dandavis that's a good point. When a 30 gallon heater dominated our kitchen, we had a fully functional house (except for lighting and internet) when power was out.  Empire/Williams furnace FTW. Now that we have a gas tankless, we need a small electric source to get hot water.  That said, if you're going to power a water heater off generator or battery, heat pump FTW, because you're not making any heat. It's free A/C, or if you are in heating season you get the heat from fuel or district heating.

Comment: Evidently you were so interested in self-answering (which is fine, of itself) that you didn't provide adequate information in your question, such as your actual costs for propane and electricity, the source of heating for your house (which you may also be changing, but again, only you know that, because you're [apparently] all about the self-answer, not about writing a clear, detailed, specific, answerable question.) The costs of both propane and electricity vary rather widely across NY state. Heck, there's a few towns that still own their dams and have municipal 5 cent/kwh power...

Comment: How did you make a Bradford White propane water heater last 27 years? Is this a "glass lined" steel tank? Monel metal tanks would last decades, but never heard of a steel tank. Do you demineralize (soften) the water going into the tank? What temperature do you have it set at? Our Bosch 125 B NG has been in service 18 yr (since Aug 2005), but I never had a tank last more than about 12 yr in Dallas TX. We do not soften the water going into the water heater. Our Bosch Aquastar 125 B NG  (discontinued model in 2005) does not have electronic controls, but has a standing pilot! No longer allowed.

Comment: @JimStewart that's a good question! Nothing special was done.  Just well water plus a UV & silt filter. Maybe we got pretty lucky.  The sacrificial anodes were totally kaput when I took them out.

Answer (score 2):

Given 60 minutes of hot water usage a day, a propane current heater, and NY location, you can expect to spend about $680 annually on fuel.

A new heat pump water heater costs about $2k for the hardware, plus additional for the install.  NY residents can claim $700 in rebates as well as a 30% tax credit, bringing the cost down to $1,400 (assuming $1k for installation).  For low income households, a lot more of than can soon be covered through HEEHRA.

In comparison, a new gas heater might cost $600, plus $1,000 for installation, totaling $1,600.

A heat pump water heater is about 4x efficient, meaning it will only cost about $189 annually with your electric rates.

Your upgrade will pay for itself in less than three years, and then save you about $491 annually every year after.  If you have solar, your electric costs are ~fixed.

For winter operation, and depending on the location of the water heater, you may want to replace the heat taken out of the air.  With an air-to-air heat pump, that adds about another $90 annually in electric costs.

I put this together with the following calculator (full disclosure - a calculator which I made), which easily lets you tune for your specific circumstances! [https://thezeropercentclub.org/water/](https://thezeropercentclub.org/water/?utm_source=diystack)

Comment: Hi Peter, while most of your answer has value, it ends with self promotion. One of the things to do is to declare your affiliation. Please read https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: Thanks! I've added that.

Comment: This is actually quite interesting. I am a big proponent of looking at **Total Cost of Ownership**. But two changes I would consider: 1 - I don't know anyone who thinks in terms of "minutes of water". Either provide an alternative in *gallons*, or put in a few lines to let people tweak the numbers based on typical usage: Showers (number x minutes, x GPM), general usage (minutes x GPM), dishwasher (gallons/load x loads), laundry (gallons/load x loads), etc. 2 - Most people are not going to replace their hot water heater until it is (a) old or (b) leaking, so an additional factor is

Comment: the cost of a regular water heater replacement. That actually helps your calculation, because instead of $2,000 vs. $0 for the unit it becomes $2,000 vs. $800 (or whatever). But this is a good start!

Comment: Heat pump water heater requires a drain for condensate that can be an extra expense to plumb in if there isn't a usable drain in the area.

Comment: How would you evaluate the net cost of a split heat pump water heater with heating outside and water tranferred to  a storage tank of stainless steel or fiberglass epoxy inside? What is the expected lifetime of a heat pump WH with the heat pump on top of the tank? How often would it need a professional service call? Should the water going into the WH be softened?

Comment: Would the OP discuss the electric power requirements for a heat pump WH. If replacing a gas fired tank, it would likely require a new circuit. Would this be a dedicated 20 A 120 V circuit or a 30 A 240 V?

Comment: @JimStewart -- most hybrids require 30A@240V, but there are unitary heat-pump-only units that can run on a 120V circuit at the cost of having almost no first hour recovery to speak of.  (if you're stuck with a 15A circuit, you're better off switching it to 240V and using a split-system HPWH)

Comment: Doesn't the location of the air intake for the HPWH have a big impact here? Using HVAC-warmed interior air vs. unconditioned indoor air (e.g. garage) vs. outside air (closet with door to outside).

Comment: So "hybrids" have two resistance elements to increase recovery. Are these lower power than the resistance elements in a straight electric resistance WH? Personally I would choose a non-hybrid heat pump because that would seem to be more robust (no penetrations of the tank) but I recognize that some people are providing for,  and dealing with, large family groups who must be provided the amount of hot water they want or there will be vociferous complaints.